# Using Ajax for real time graphical display

Tags: html, ajax, d3.js

I am doing a sample project using d3js sample from bl.ocks.org to plot graph. There is a csv file which is continuously updated. My task is to read it every second and update the plot. I tried to look up ajax example to add into the d3. However bl.ocks.org did not have what I needed. Can anyone please let me know a good ajax example which I can integrate with my application. 
--> next task is to get csv off and have a restful service to read data. Then it is to be parsed and graph is to be updated periodically.
Thanks in advance!

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style> /* set the CSS */

    body { font: 12px Arial;}

    path { 
        stroke: steelblue;
        stroke-width: 2;
        fill: none;
    }

    .axis path,
    .axis line {
        fill: none;
        stroke: grey;
        stroke-width: 1;
        shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }

    </style>
    <body>

    <!-- load the d3.js library -->    
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

    <script>

    // Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
    var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
        width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    // Parse the date / time
    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;

    // Set the ranges
    var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
    var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

    // Define the axes
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
        .orient("bottom").ticks(5);

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
        .orient("left").ticks(5);

    // Define the line
    var valueline = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
        .y(function(d) { return y(d.close); });

    // Adds the svg canvas
    var svg = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
            .attr("transform", 
                  "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    // Get the data
    d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
        data.forEach(function(d) {
            d.date = parseDate(d.date);
            d.close = +d.close;
        });

        // Scale the range of the data
        x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
        y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.close; })]);

        // Add the valueline path.
        svg.append("path")
            .attr("class", "line")
            .attr("d", valueline(data));

        // Add the X Axis
        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(xAxis);

        // Add the Y Axis
        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "y axis")
            .call(yAxis);

    });



    </script>
    </body>
```

Comment: put in the code that you tried so that the issue is more understandable...

Comment: Hi Prashanth, added the file.. Mostly I have embed ajax poll inside <script> secondly, csv read is to be eliminated and RESTful is to be added from which data will come and graph will get updated periodically.